# farthest point voronoi diagram of 3 points

Tags: computational-geometry, voronoi

This is really more of a math question. But given 3 points how do you calculate the farthest point voronoi diagram?

Start by finding circle that passes through all of them and grabbing its center. Not sure where to go from here. It's weird to picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw the bisectors between each pair of points, from the circle center outward:

[image: furthest point VorDiag]!

Comment: Ah beautiful, makes much more sense. Thanks

Comment: @josephorourke: May I know what tool you used to create this diagram? :-)

Comment: @Ashwin: Adobe Illustrator.