# Voronoi Diagram Explanation

Tags: scikit-learn, voronoi, scipy-spatial

I am trying to generate Voronoi split polygons and not able to understand the parameter 'furthest_site=True' in Voronoi's Scipy's implementation.

> from scipy.spatial import Voronoi, voronoi_plot_2d
>
> points = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2],
> [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]])
>
> vor = Voronoi(points,furthest_site=True)
>
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> fig = voronoi_plot_2d(vor) plt.show()

This gives me output as :
[image]

What is the explanation for attribute "furthest_site=True"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scipy says it uses QHull to compute voronoi diagrams, and they have this [in their documentation](http://www.qhull.org/html/qvoron_f.htm):

> The furthest-site Voronoi diagram is the furthest-neighbor map for a set of points. Each region contains those points that are further from one input site than any other input site.

Furthest (or "farthest")-site diagrams are described in plenty of other places, including example diagrams; for example, in other stackexchange posts: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3197057/493872), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867844/10495893).

Your plot looks odd because your pointset is somewhat degenerate; only the four corner points ever serve as the furthest reference point.